# Efficient way to store dictionary (hash) in file with python?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, serialization

I'm implementing a Unix userland tool that needs to store a hash on the disk. The hash will be read every run of the program, pretty frequently. The hash needs to store "name:path" values only.

I looked at the [bsddb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html) standard library module for python, but I can see it will be deprecated in Python 3. I also saw the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) standard library module.

I'm not a python guy, so what is the efficient way for hash serialization and frequent open/read/close operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) module and see if that isn't too slow. It does exactly what you want.

```
import shelve

d = shelve.open('filename')

d['name'] = 'path'

d.close()
```

or to read from it

```
d = shelve.open('filename')

d = hash['name']
```

It's essentially a wrapper around pickle that provides a dictionary abstraction.

Comment: +1 Cool, never heard of that module before. -0.1 for shadowing `hash`, though. :o) ... ok, that's been removed now.

Comment: @jellybean, something looked wrong to me. changed it to `d` to reflect the fact that it's essentially a dict. good looking out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use pickle and see if it's fast enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use pickle / shelve for serialization of data.

- http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/saving-python-dict-to-file-using-pickle/
- http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html